# Linux Security Best practice: CAP_SETFCAP vs sudoer file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sudo, capabilities

I am new to linux securities and tried to understand what's the best practice for linux capabilities. Here is my scenario:

I have an executable file (let's call it `foo`) which needs to grant `CAP_SYS_NICE` to some other executables. Basically I have two way to do that:

1. add a rule in sudoer file to allow the user who starts `foo` to call `setcap` binary to grant `CAP_SYS_NICE`. e.g. something like this `user  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/setcap cap_sys_nice+epi /path/to/target/directory/*` and then use `system` function to start a new shell to run the `/user/sbin/setcap`.
2. Grant `CAP_SETFCAP` to executable `foo` so that in the executable `foo` I can call some linux system function i.e. `cap_set_file` https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_set_file

Can someone tells me what's the pros/cons for each and what's the best practice to such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to write a dedicated program that grants `CAP_SYS_NICE` to a target binary in the manner you need.

If there is some filename pattern, ownership, or other property of the target binary that it must have, check for that detail in the code for the dedicated program before applying the capability. A simple example:

```c
/* make_nice.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

#ifndef base
#define base "/only/allowed/base/directory/"
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static cap_value_t c_sys_nice = CAP_SYS_NICE;
    static cap_value_t c_setfcap = CAP_SETFCAP;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: make_nice <path>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (strncmp(argv[1], base, sizeof(base)-1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "<path> must have prefix: %s\n", base);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (strstr(argv[1], "/../") != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "<path> must not contain /../\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* should probably confirm no symlinks in argv[1] too... */
    cap_t fc = cap_init();
    if (fc == NULL) {
        perror("no memory for cap_t");
        exit(1);
    }
    cap_t pc = cap_get_proc();
    if (pc == NULL) {
        perror("serious problem");
        exit(1);
    }
    cap_set_flag(pc, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 1, &c_setfcap, CAP_SET);
    if (cap_set_proc(pc)) {
        perror("failed to raise CAP_SETFCAP");
        exit(1);
    }
    cap_set_flag(fc, CAP_PERMITTED, 1, &c_sys_nice, CAP_SET);
    if (cap_set_file(argv[1], fc)) {
        perror("failed to set CAP_SYS_NICE");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

For testing purposes compile like this and run it:

```
$ gcc -Dbase=\"$(pwd)/\" make_nice.c -o make_nice -lcap
$ sudo setcap cap_setfcap=p ./make_nice
$ touch test_target
$ ./make_nice $(pwd)/test_target
$ getcap -r .
./test_target cap_sys_nice=p
./make_nice cap_setfcap=p
```

The best practice parts are:

1. The `make_nice` code has the responsibility for ensuring it is only applying the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability to files that should have it.

   - in some cases you might even compile the binary `--static` to avoid any surprises from `glibc` being upgraded...
2. You can augment the `make_nice` binary with an ACL. For example, make the program *group* executable, but not *other* executable (`chmod o-rwx ./make_nice`) and only allow members of that *group* (`sudo chgrp nicefolk ./make_nice`) to run it.